# Does copy constructors have return value in C++

Tags: c++

I understood the concept of copy constructor. Till now I was thinking that copy constructors won't have return values. But I saw some code on internet regarding smart pointers, which defines copy constructor as returning some value. Is it correct? Does Copy constructors in C++ have return values?

Comment: *No* constructor has a return value. An assignment *operator* (`operator =`), on the other hand, may.

Comment: `operator =` is more commonly referred to as an *assignment operator*. In most languages, the r-value is usually returned by the assignment operation (i.e. `(l = r) == r`). @dlf is correct, though; constructors *never* return a value.

Comment: If you shared the code, we'd be able to say more.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Constructors (in general) do not have a return type, nor do they return a value:

> No return type (not even void) shall be specified for a constructor. A return statement in the body of a constructor shall not specify a return value.
>
> §12.1 [class.ctor]

You may be thinking of the [copy assignment operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_operator), which does something different, but related, and looks like:

```
T & operator = (const T &);
```

Comment: When you qualify your statement with "in general", to me that implies there are exceptions. Are there any?

Comment: @MGaz: It means the opposite.  It means that what I'm saying applies to **all** constructors, not just copy constructors.

Comment: @RobertAllanHenniganLeahy - actually I'm with MGaz on this one. In general implies that are are some circumstances where the general principal does not apply.

Comment: "General" used to mean "in all cases without exceptions" (the Latin root translates literally to "all of a genus"), but like many words, it's had its meaning broadened over time to the point that it now conveys something more like "in the majority of cases, disregarding the occasional exception." So... both interpretations are possible, and it's probably best to qualify.

Answer (score 1):

Constructors do not have return types .But can have access specifiers . 
If a constructor is attached with a return type ...compiler treats it as a function