# Does a C++ constructor have a return value ? (implicit or explicit)

Tags: c++, object, c++11, constructor

I was wondering and couldn't find a reliable source to answer my question :
Does a construtor implicitly return the value of the type of the object itself ?

my sources : https://blog.miyozinc.com/core-tutorials/cpp/cpp-constructors-destructors/ (does return)

[Does copy constructors have return value in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25311671/does-copy-constructors-have-return-value-in-c) (does not return)

Comment: What's wrong with this answer [Constructors (in general) do not have a return type, nor do they return a value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25311761/7478597)? It even cites the resp. rule of the standard.

Comment: In the [first link](https://blog.miyozinc.com/core-tutorials/cpp/cpp-constructors-destructors/), it's stated: _Constructors have no return type, not even void._ (The rest reads a bit confusing.)

Comment: A class may be instanced as temporary. That's denoting the class name with constructor arguments e.g. `std::filesystem::path curDir(std::string("."));` This constructs an RValue of `std::string` (a temporary instance) which is passed into `std::filesystem::path::path()`. It looks like whether the constructor would return a class instance but actually the (temporary) object is created and then the constructor of it is called. So, is this the constructor which returns the instance? I think: No.

Comment: What do you mean by *"implicit return"*? `main` implicit returns `0`, but I don't think it is the meaning you have.

Comment: Well, I don't think that my question has a "real" utility. But tbh i have done an exam and I need to know if a constructor return ANYTHING, even if its implicit. As i answered previously in an other comment : "Yes i know that it is impossible explicitly (my title was not precise) but I still don't know if it return something implicitly", I just need to know if it return anything implicitly

Comment: What would be different about the language if it did, versus if it did not?

Comment: The constructor creates the object in-place, by modifying `*this`. It does not need to return anything, and there is nowhere for it to return a value to. (Constructors are not normal functions.)

Comment: The question I need to be answered is : "Do constructors return nothing ?", so I know that explicitly it is impossible, but implicitly I have a doubt

Comment: Constructors don't have a return type, and the constructor is not allowed to specify a return value (e.g.  `return any_value` is not permitted in a constructor).   There is an idiom known as a "virtual constructor" that is sometimes - erroneously - interpreted as meaning that a constructor can be virtual so (since virtual functions need a return type in C++) that it must have a return type.   The term "virtual constructor", ironically, is an abstraction that has no bearing on whether a constructor is a virtual function.

Answer (score 5):

No.

As per [[class.ctor]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/class.ctor#6):

> A return statement in the body of a constructor shall not specify a return value. The address of a constructor shall not be taken.

And, similarly [[stmt.return]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/stmt.return#1) and [[stmt.return]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/stmt.return#2):

> /1 A function **returns to its caller** by the return statement.
>
> /2 [...] A return statement with no operand shall be used only in a
> function whose return type is cv void, a constructor, or a destructor.
> [...] **Flowing off the end of a constructor**, a destructor, or a
> non-coroutine function with a cv void return type **is equivalent to a return with no operand.**

Constructors do not have return values, but after their completion they *return to its caller*.

```
struct S {
    S(int) { }   
};

int main() {
    S s{42};
}
```

is equivalent to

```
struct S {
    S(int) { return; }   
};

int main() {
    S s{42};
}
```

Finally, return *values* are relevant in the context of *function calls*, but none of `S s{42}`, `S{42}`, `S s(42)` or `S(42)` is a function call, it is [initialization](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.init) for the case where [an initializer follows a declarator](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.dcl#nt:simple-declaration).

Comment: Yes i know that it is impossible explicitly (my title was not precise) but I still don't know if it return something implicitly

Comment: @santoro The c++ standard and the implementation of it is two different things. If your asking what the language says about it, here is your answer. If you are wondering about the compiler implementation, there is no general answer. As long as an implementation follows the rules of the language, it can do what it wants under the hood and the different compilers will do different things.

Comment: I am not sure to understand this right, but it does not say anything about an implicit return value

Comment: @santoro Return _values_ (not the return statement) is only relevant in the context of function calls. Whilst a constructor is a function, `S(42)` for a class `S` (assuming there's not user-defined conversion _functions_ in place) is not a function _call_, it is initialization.

Comment: Well ok I think that I understand what you are saying but what do you answer to : "Do constructors return nothing ?", so I know that explicitly it is impossible, but implicitly I have a doubt. Because I think that they implicitly return the object itself

Comment: @santoro only case of implicit return in C++  is `main()` and even in that case it's not called that.  Constructor may result in no code at all, and call to constructor is part of initialization of  object pointed by `this`, so in no way constructor can return that object. Returning implies creation of new temporary  object or passing a copy of object in automatic storage.  Those two conflict with each other in terms of C++, because in order to create a temporary or automatic object, constructor have to call itself.

Answer (score 1):

No. A constructor creates an object in a specific location. This location is names `this` in the constructor, just as it's name `this` in the destructor and all other member functions. `this` might be considered an "implicit argument" to all member functions, but `this` is not an "implicit return value" of any member function.

Comment: So you consider [link[(https://blog.miyozinc.com/core-tutorials/cpp/cpp-constructors-destructors/) "Constructors have no return type, not even void. This is because the implicit return type of a class’ constructor is the class type itself. It is the constructor’s job to initialize the internal state of an object so that the code creating an instance will have a fully initialized, usable object immediately." false ?

Comment: @santoro: Correct, that is indeed false.  Compilers typically implement constructors as a function with one extra hidden argument,, but no return value.

Comment: @MSalters it could be that author of that was coming from point of view of certain architectures where caller manages the stack and address of return value is passed to called subroutine. In that case passing an argument by pointer and facilitating return of some objects are same thing. This is purely historical, imo. It's not same from high-level perspective.